# Two measures are equivalent iff their image measures have same support?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space, $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$ a measurable map and $\mathbb P$, $\mathbb Q$ two probability measures. Let $\mu_\mathbb P=\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}$ and $\mu_\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q\circ X^{-1}.$ Is it true that $\mathbb P$ is equivalent to $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $\text{supp}(\mu_\mathbb P)=\text{supp}(\mu_\mathbb Q)$?  Here we define the support of a Borel probability measure as the smallest closed set such that its complement has measure zero. One direction is clear, how about the other?Counterexample? Maybe I am just overseeing something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untrue. Consider $\Omega=\mathbb R^d$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, $X$ the identity, and $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ some discrete probability measures with positive weights at the elements of some countable sets $S$ and $T$, respectively.

Then the supports of $\mathbb P=\mu_\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q=\mu_\mathbb Q$ are the closures of $S$ and $T$. These may coincide while $S\cap T$ is empty, that is, one can have $\mathrm{supp}(\mu_\mathbb P)=\mathrm{supp}(\mu_\mathbb Q)$ while $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ are mutually singular.

Example: if $d=1$, one can choose $S$ the set of rational numbers whose reduced form has an even denominator and $T$ the set of rational numbers whose reduced form has an odd denominator.

Comment: how did you arrive at the conclusion that $supp(\mu_{\mathscr{P}}) = supp(\mu_{\mathscr{Q}})$ when $S\cap T = \emptyset$?

Comment: @user177196 This implication is not in my post. What the post says is that one **can** have both simultaneously.

Comment: I meant, for your example, why does it work?

Comment: @user177196 I hope the part $S\cap T=\varnothing$ is not a problem. To see why the supports are equal, the simplest approach is to show they are both $\mathbb R$. Can you do that?

Comment: That's the part that confused me. Because given $x\in R$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the open interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ contains at least one rational numbers. But we don't know the reduced form of these rational numbers, so we cannot say *BOTH* $P((x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon))>0$ and $Q((x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon))>0$....

Comment: @user177196 Cannot you show that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains a rational number whose reduced form has an even denominator?

Comment: obviously, it's not true, right? And what about $(\sqrt{3}-0.01, \sqrt{3}+0.01)$?

Comment: @user177196 Yes it is true that every interval $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ contains a rational number whose reduced form has an even denominator. Re your example, consider $$\frac{34641}{20000}$$

Comment: I don't know how to show that;p But then wouldn't we need to show the same thing for odd denominator?

Comment: @user177196 "I don't know how to show that;p" Well, this is very surprising. Anyway, it might be better to post this as a separate question, to avoid further hijacking this thread. "But then wouldn't we need to show the same thing for odd denominator?" Yes we would, and that would be equally direct.